# Circular progress bar thickness

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

Is there a way to increase the thickness of the progressbar when using the circular style?
I can't find any documentation about it on github.

Comment: `MaterialDesignCircularProgressBar`?

Comment: It looks like [this](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/d69dd940ad60bafc8711fdc3926f5d7abfcba63b/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ProgressBar.xaml#L160) is where it is set (`StrokeThickness`).  As you can see, it's hard-coded, so you'd have to create a derived style to change it.

Answer (score 5):

The way I get around this, without doing anything outside XAML or modifying the template, is to use a combination of:

- Width/Height
- ScaleTransform

Example below, I generally play around with the split between scale and width/height until I'm happy with how it looks.

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCircularProgressBar}" Width="50" Height="50">
  <ProgressBar.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
  </ProgressBar.LayoutTransform>
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Robert Harvey answer, I found a better solution. Instead of copying the whole style, and change the hardcoded value by another hardcoded value, I created a behavior to change the thickness value.

```
 public class CircularProgressBarBehavior : StyleBehavior<ProgressBar, CircularProgressBarBehavior>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressBarBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(3d));

    public static double GetStrokeThickness(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        return (double) dependencyObject.GetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached(); 

        // ReSharper disable once CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator
        var path = AssociatedObject.GetChildren<Path>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.Equals("Path"));

        if (path != null)
            path.StrokeThickness = GetStrokeThickness(AssociatedObject);
    }

    public static void SetStrokeThickness(DependencyObject dependencyObject, double value)
    {
        dependencyObject.SetValue(StrokeThicknessProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be added to the xaml.cs (code behind) of the WPF where you're using the progress bar? Also, I'm not sure what type/namespace "StyleBehavior" comes from says I'm missing a "using" directive or assembly reference.